# ASP.NET Core MVC - How to display data from Excel into HTML table before inserting into the DB

Tags: excel, asp.net-core

In ASP.NET Core-6 MVC, I have excel file (student.xlsx) with this code:

Model:

```
public class Students
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int AdmissionYear { get; set; }
    public string RegistrationNo { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file)
    {
        if (file == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        List<Students> studentList = new List<Student>();
        
        using(var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await file.CopyToAsync(memoryStream).ConfigureAwait(false);
            using(var package = new ExcelPackage(memoryStream))
            {
                var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
                if (worksheet.Dimension.Rows > 0 && worksheet.Dimension.Columns > 0)
                {
                    for (int row = 2; row <= worksheet.Dimension.Rows; row++)   // start at row 2 to skip header
                    {
                        Students student = new Students();
                        student.FirstName = worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value.ToString();
                        student.LastName = worksheet.Cells[row, 2].Value.ToString();
                        student.AdmissionYear = int.Parse(worksheet.Cells[row, 3].Value.ToString());
                        student.RegistrationNo = worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Value.ToString();
                        studentList.Add(student);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return View("Index", studentList);
    }
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label name-for="file">Excel xlsx Upload</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" />      
</div>
<input type="button" name="display" value="Show Data" id="btnShow" class="btn btn-primary" />

<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="table-head">
           <input type="checkbox" onchange="checkAll(this)" name="chk[]" />
        </th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>AdmissionYear</th>
        <th>RegistrationNo</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td valign="middle" align="center" style="width: 2%;">
                    <input type="checkbox" onchange="checkSingle(this)" name="chk[]" />
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td> </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

</table>
```

As soon as the user choose the excel file to be uploaded, when he clicks on choose file, and clicks on Show Data, it should display the excel data in the table in html without even the submit upload button

I want to first display the imported data into HTML table in the view page before the user then submits and insert into the DB.

[image: excel-upload]

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: I would move your second question out of this post. The scope would be too big. Focus on your first question and later on tackle the UI related stuff, since you haven't shown us your javascript bits and bobs at all, yet.

Comment: Break your goal down into small tasks - do you know how to read data from an Excel file in C#? Extract that data and store it into memory in some form? Do you know how to build a View that shows data from an object? Do you know how to insert data into a database? Which specific parts are you struggling with? It appears you got some of this already implemented in your code, so it's not clear which part you're stuck on.

Comment: You might be trying to over-complicate it.  Why avoid saving data in the database?  Just change how you arrange and maintain that data.  Store it in the DB in a kind of "temporary" state.  Maybe have a column indicating "committed" status and default it to something like "pending".  Then show that data to the user.  The user can approve or reject it, which would "commit" or delete it.

Comment: @mason - When I mean is that as soon as the user choose the excel file to be uploaded, when he clicks on choose file, and clicks on Show Data, it should display the excel data in the table in html without even the submit upload button

Comment: Do you mean that clicking the ShowData button only loads the contents of Excel in this page? Don't need to upload and store content to a database?

Comment: @Chen - Yes, but there is another button to store it into the database

Comment: I updated my answer, you can try it. @Ayobamilaye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to monitor the status of the file, then read the file and load it through `xlsx.full`.

You can refer to my test code below:

```
    <div class="container">
    <h2 class="text-center mt-4 mb-4">Convert Excel to HTML Table using JavaScript</h2>
    <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header"><b>Select Excel File</b></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <input type="file" name="file" id="excel_file" />
                <input type="button" name="display" value="Show Data" id="btnShow" onclick="ShowData()" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
    </div>
    <div id="excel_data" class="mt-5"></div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonyous" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/xlsx@0.15.1/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var table_output = "";
    var excel_file = document.getElementById("excel_file");
    excel_file.addEventListener("change",(event) =>{

        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(event.target.files[0]);

        reader.onload = function(event){
            var data = new Uint8Array(reader.result);

            var work_book = XLSX.read(data,{type:'array'});

            var sheet_name = work_book.SheetNames;

            var sheet_data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(work_book.Sheets[sheet_name[0]],{hearder:1});
            
            if(sheet_data.length > 0)
            {
                table_output += '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">';

                table_output += '<thead><tr><th>First Name </th><th> Last Name </th><th> AdmissionYear </th><th> RegistrationNo </th></tr></thead>';
                table_output += '<tbody>';

                for(var row = 0; row < sheet_data.length; row++)
                {
                    table_output += '<tr>';
                    table_output += '<td>' + sheet_data[row].FirstName + '</td>';
                    table_output += '<td>' + sheet_data[row].LastName + '</td>';
                    table_output += '<td>' + sheet_data[row].AdmissionYear + '</td>';
                    table_output += '<td>' + sheet_data[row].RegistrationNo + '</td>';
                    table_output += '</tr>';
                }

                table_output += '</tbody></table>';
            }
        }
    })
    function ShowData()
    {
        document.getElementById("excel_data").innerHTML = table_output;
    }

</script>
```

Test Result:
[image]
When file is selected and ShowData is clicked:
[image]
Hope this can help you.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort, it works. But As shown in my updated code, I am using datatable with checkbox. I'm finding it difficult to implement your code properly. Kindly assist

Comment: What about splicing the checkboxes to the first column of each row? @Ayobamilaye

Comment: The checkbox works but the pagination and search in the datatable are no more being display. I use id=example1 for the datatable. Can you show me a sample?

Answer (score -1):

1. You can import the Sheetjs library which can read your excel file and render it to a table. [Demo](https://sheetjs.com/sql/)
2. The library can read your data into Json, you can modify that Json to add an empty column and then hook into the render event to render the checkbox.